# trying to use canvas.create_window() method, getting an error from within tk

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

--edit-- Solved in comments, I should have been using plain arguments, not keyword arguments for x and y in the create_window() call. I'll accept an answer as soon as jasonharper writes it --edit--

I'm using python 3.8.10, with tkinter 8.6, under Mint 20.1. I'm trying to put widgets onto a canvas, using canvas.create_window(x, y, window=widget). Ultimately they'll be my own objects inheriting from tki.Canvas, but that doesn't seem to be the problem, as I can't place native tki.Buttons either.

I'm creating the canvas and the widgets under the same parent. I'm keeping a copy of the widget, so it's not being garbage collected. Gridding the widgets onto a frame works fine. I arrived at [python.hotexamples](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/Tkinter/Canvas/create_window/python-canvas-create_window-method-examples.html) after searching for examples of create_window, and the syntax I'm using seems to be the same. I've checked the questions involving create_window here, and none have a similar error.

Here's a (more or less) minimal program. Boolean constants BUTTON and CANVAS allow me to select a button or custom widget, and place on a canvas or frame.

```
#!/home/neil/pye/bin/python

import tkinter as tki

CELL_SIZE = 50
TEXT_BASE = 30

CANVAS = False
BUTTON = True

class MyWidget(tki.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, row, col):
        tki.Canvas.__init__(self, master=parent,
                            width=CELL_SIZE, height=CELL_SIZE,
                            relief=tki.SOLID, bd=3)
        self.create_text(TEXT_BASE, TEXT_BASE, text=f'M r={row}\n{col=}')

class Board(tki.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tki.Frame.__init__(self, master=parent)
        self.cells = []

        if CANVAS:        
            self.c = tki.Canvas(self, width=4*CELL_SIZE, height=4*CELL_SIZE)
            self.c.grid()
        
        # do a grid of widgets
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(2):
                if BUTTON:
                    b = tki.Button(self, text=f'B r={row}\n{col=}')
                else:
                    b = MyWidget(self, row, col)
                    
                self.cells.append(b)

                if CANVAS:                  
                    self.c.create_window(x=CELL_SIZE*col,
                                         y=CELL_SIZE*row,
                                         window=b)
                else:
                    b.grid(row=row, column=col)
   
if __name__ == '__main__':                                
    root = tki.Tk()
    app = Board(root)
    app.pack()
    app.mainloop()
```

Whenever CANVAS = True, I get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_canvas_window.py", line 58, in <module>
    app = App(root)
  File "./test_canvas_window.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.b = Board(self)
  File "./test_canvas_window.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.c.create_window(x=CELL_SIZE*col,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2814, in create_window
    return self._create('window', args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2771, in _create
    cnf = args[-1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

... which suggests that something is wrong with the syntax, and what handles the create_window call is expecting more stuff, but it's being rather coy about exactly what.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `x` and `y` values to `.create_window()` can't be specified with keyword parameters, they have to be ordinary positional parameters.

Comment: @jasonharper Doh! How many times have I compared those examples and missed that? It works. Thanks. Answer it and I'll accept.

Comment: @jasonharper Ah! It was actually telling me that it didn't have any args, only kwargs, just not as clearly as you.